# Error configuring mcrypt after upgrading to El Capitam

Tags: mcrypt, osx-elcapitan

I am facing the following issue after upgrading to El Capitan. It says:

"Installing shared extensions: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ cp: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/#INST@826#: Operation not permitted"

while configuring mcrypt.

Comment: You might post your question at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to OS X 10.11 El Capitan's Rootless feature. 
To install the extension into /usr/lib/php/* you need temporarily disable the feature.
1. Boot into recovery mode (while booting hold down Command+R)
2. Enter **csrutil disable** in terminal
3. Restart computer and System Integrity Protection will be disabled.
Don't Forget to re-enable it afterwards (**csrutil enable** also in recovery mode)